# How to keep Screen Name in sync with Profile channel fields using Profile:Edit

Tags: channel-entries, profile-edit

I'm using Profile:Edit 1.0.9 with EE 2.5.5, and finding that the Screen Name is sometimes coming out of sync with the First Name and Last Name custom fields in the profile entry (when a user edits their profile).

Is there a way to keep the Screen Name in sync should the first and last name be amended? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the dynamic_screen_name="[member_first_name] [member_last_name]" parameter?

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm using dynamic_screen_name in the exp:profile:register tag, but not with the exp:profile:edit tag. Are you saying that this parameter can also be used in the exp:profile:register tag to keep them in sync? My 'out of sync' issue only happens when users are editing their profile later (it's a site where they can change their name if needed, so end up with a First and Last Name that says one thing, and a Screen name says another).

Comment: I just tried adding the dynamic_screen_name parameter to the exp:profile:edit tag but after saving the record, I got a load of PHP errors, and found that the Screen Name had changed to: "[member_first_name] [member_last_name]".

Comment: So I'm guessing this isn't possible, and the only option left is to run an update query from time to time to overwrite the Screen Name with the 'first_name last_name'. My only concern then is that doing this via SQL might give lots of duplicate Screen Names, but I can't think think of any issues to this if it's done via SQL (as opposed to via EE, which insists they're unique otherwise).

Comment: My mistake, looks like that param is only on the register tag. I don't see any issue with duplicate screen names.

Comment: Okay thanks Rob. I'll submit it to Mighty Big Robot as a feature request, and will go the SQL route in the meantime.