# Duplicate screen names with Profile:Edit

Tags: profile-edit

During registration the {exp:profile:register} tag checks for duplicate screen names, however when editing an existing profile with the {exp:profile:edit} tag it does not appear to check for duplicates therefore letting me create duplicate screen names. Does anyone know if this is a bug or working as expected. I have tested this with the default Profile:Edit templates.

Comment: Please select an answer or give more info as to why none of the answers work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this too: Profile:Edit does prevent duplicate member email addresses and usernames, which is needs too. But, not screen names.

Note that Rob from Mighty Big Robot commented on this issue, before, on this site:

[How to keep Screen Name in sync with Profile channel fields using Profile:Edit](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9951/how-to-keep-screen-name-in-sync-with-profile-channel-fields-using-profileedit?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

ExpressionEngine's own registration process checks for duplicate screen names. So, Profile:Edit should be doing so as well. It's possibly a bug or oversight that it doesn't do so upon editing.